# vba transpose single row to multiple rows in an array

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, split, transpose

I would like to transpose comma separated values (or any delimiter) to multiple rows in an array. Most of the examples I'm seeing are saved to a range value in excel file.
Could any please advise.

strFirstLine:

```
 row1,row2,row3
```

Ouput in Array so I could loop on each line for manipulation:

```
  row1
  row2
  row3
```

Here is the code I have so far. I have added comment on the debug.print part.

```
line = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Split(strFirstLine, ","))

ctr = 0
For ctr = LBound(line) To UBound(line)
    Debug.Print LBound(line) --value is 1
    Debug.Print UBound(line) --value is 13
    Debug.Print CStr(line(LBound(line))) --this line fails with "Subscript out of Range" error 
Next ctr
```

Let me know if you need more details. Any  thoughts will be appreciated!

Comment: You dont need vba for this, Excel alredy does this for free

Comment: The transpose? yes it does, but I need to do some manipulation with the data, thus I want to saved it in an array and access it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid transpose function. Simply use split and define row and column value where you want to save the split values and its done.

Check this code:

```
Sub try()
Dim Line() As String
Dim ctr, rw, cl As Integer

strFirstLine = "row1,row2,row3"

Line = Split(strFirstLine, ",")

ctr = 0
rw = 1
cl = 1
For ctr = LBound(Line) To UBound(Line)
    Cells(rw, cl) = Line(ctr)
    rw = rw + 1
Next ctr

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

`line` here is a 2-d array, so you need to specify the dimension when using `LBound` or `UBound`, and you need both indexes when accessing a value:

```
line = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Split("row1,row2,row3", ","))

Debug.Print LBound(line, 1), UBound(line, 1) '1,3
Debug.Print LBound(line, 2), UBound(line, 2) '1,1


For ctr = LBound(line, 1) To UBound(line, 1)
    Debug.Print line(ctr, 1)
Next ctr
```

Comment: Thanks!! Just out of curiosity, is there a reason to do it in 2D array? Can this be done in 1D array like a list or something? This works good though, thanks again.

Comment: I assumed you for some reason *wanted* a 2-D array, but @Paresh J shows how to get a 1-d version